# JSON code with escaped qoutes

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got this JSON code in a string and I'm trying to get the original title,... out of it. I'm usig JSON.NET but it wont work because every qoutation is escaped by an '/'. If I want to Replace the /" to " in C#, nothing happens..

```
string s = "{\"page\":1,\"results\":[{\"adult\":false,\"backdrop_path\":\"/      mMblxwsvvJ9wu8CVXVVjX4MBuN2.jpg\",\"id\":957,\"original_title\":\"Spaceballs\",\"release_date    \":\"1987-06-24\",\"poster_path\":\"/9lBOjli8TrJghuzAulVNJvTNJCS.jpg\",    \"popularity\":3.25235847573851,\"title\":\"Spaceballs\",\"vote_average\":7.7,\"vote_count    \":35},{\"adult\":false,\"backdrop_path\":null,\"id\":56297,\"original_title\":\"Spaceballs:     The Documentary\",\"release_date\":\"2005-05-05\",\"poster_path\":\"/    kPVdkoT49zP8RcruDP3AtquZ7WT.jpg\",\"popularity\":0.46,\"title\":\"Spaceballs: The Documentary    \",\"vote_average\":6.0,\"vote_count\":1}],\"total_pages\":1,\"total_results\":2}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the model class details, you can use the following code

```
ModelClass myDeserializedObj = (ModelClass)JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject(s, typeof(ModelClass));
```

This way you do not need to manually handle the JSON reading part. IF you are using ASP.Net MVC, you can do auto model binding so that MVC does this for you out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input ="{\"page\":1,\"results\":[{\"adult\":false,\"backdrop_path\":\"/  mMblxwsvvJ9wu8CVXVVjX4MBuN2.jpg\",\"id\":957,\"original_title\":\"Spaceballs\",\"release_date\":\"1987-06-24\",\"poster_path\":\"/9lBOjli8TrJghuzAulVNJvTNJCS.jpg\",\"popularity\":3.25235847573851,\"title\":\"Spaceballs\",\"vote_average\":7.7,\"vote_count\":35},{\"adult\":false,\"backdrop_path\":null,\"id\":56297,\"original_title\":\"Spaceballs: The Documentary\",\"release_date\":\"2005-05-05\",\"poster_path\":\"/kPVdkoT49zP8RcruDP3AtquZ7WT.jpg\",\"popularity\":0.46,\"title\":\"Spaceballs: The Documentary\",\"vote_average\":6.0,\"vote_count\":1}],\"total_pages\":1,\"total_results\":2}";
dynamic d = JObject.Parse(input);
foreach (var item in d.results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.original_title);
}
```

if you have model class you can do as below

```
var op = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllResults>(input);
foreach (var item in op.results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.original_title);
}

public class Result
{
    public bool adult { get; set; }
    public string backdrop_path { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string original_title { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__release_date { get; set; }
    public string poster_path { get; set; }
    public double popularity { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public double vote_average { get; set; }
    public int __invalid_name__vote_count { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
    public int? vote_count { get; set; }
}

public class AllResults
{
    public int page { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public int total_pages { get; set; }
    public int total_results { get; set; }
}
```

classes generated from http://json2csharp.com/